# Is there absolutely no protection for Windows applications on dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security, obfuscation

I am in the middle of developing an application in Winforms and there just doesn't seem to be any protection from decompilation of the executables and other generated assemblies... there are [tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/#section=web-installer) that decompile literally within seconds. There are obfuscators available; however, I am specifically looking for a free one.

I store some pretty sensitive strings within the application, and though I try my best to keep them encrypted or in the local sqlite database, there is always that one, single point of failure that leaves the entire application vulnerable. I checked out a couple of obfuscators, both [open source](https://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/) and [commercial](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/trial/) [offerings](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/index.html). The open source one seems to be broken, and the commercial ones are priced quite steeply, which is unaffordable for an indie developer like me.

I am aware that an executable has to run in memory, and this in itself makes it vulnerable. And a determined attacker can eventually decompile an application. However, I want to make this process as expensive as possible. At the very least I would want to protect the strings within my application.

My question is, is there just no way to protect an application assembly from getting reverse engineered if I decide not to use any of the expensive options available?

Comment: why would you ever store sensitive string in your app's code

Comment: @pm100, Where else would I store them?

Comment: @Najeeb you authenticate with a remote server and use tokens instead?

Comment: @sommmen, yes, I already do that. However, there are situations wherein I have to init a local sqlite database before I can call the server (I hardcode the server's public key within the db), and for this I willynilly have to use a local string to keep it encrypted. Even if I later get a fresh encryption string for the db from the server, it leaves the db vulnerable for that period of time.

Comment: as config strings, .net has nice support for that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @pm100, as in a config file? Wouldn't that leave them exposed? Even if I were to encrypt the config value strings with a secure algo like AES256, the problem would still remain, since I would then need to store the AES key somewhere within the application. A catch-22 situation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/dotfuscator/?view=vs-2019

Comment: WinAuth makes you enter the decryption key at startup so it is not a fixed key in the code.  With that approach a random attacker other than the user can't get to the secrets.     If you are trying to protect the local db from the owner / user then good luck.

Comment: @HansPassant, the community edition has a non-commercial clause. https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions

Comment: If you want a free solution please edit your question to include that.

Comment: @DaveS, done (y)

Comment: You haven't made it clear what you're trying to protect and from whom.  You can use DPAPI to encrypt data so that it's only accessible to the current user, and CredUI via P/Invoke to prompts for and store credentials so that they're only accessible to the current user.  You could, for example, do this when the application is installed or first run.  Neither of these will help to protect your IP, but it's not clear from your question if this is what you want to protect.

Comment: @Joe, to the maximum possible extent I would want to protect the IP; that said, I am not using anything out of the blue in this application: it uses standard cryptographic techniques. However, I would want to make the process of reverse-engineering it as expensive as possible. More importantly, my application will be publicly downloadable, and I would not want anybody to view things like my db schemas; the messaging formats between the server and the application; and so forth. This also includes jsons for various functions.

Comment: @Najeeb, for IP you don't have any protection except the limited (and as you say, sometimes costly) protection you can get by using an obfuscator.

Comment: @Joe, yes, I am also led to that way of thinking after going through the comments.. I guess I cannot have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: Can't have 100% protection with .net. And if you want a free solution,  not easy.  The other option is to use cloud based solutions: certainly cheaper for indies but there is a small overhead. E.g. https://linuxacademy.com/blog/amazon-web-services-2/an-inside-look-at-aws-secrets-manager-vs-parameter-store/

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, had thought of going along that route. Will do some re-thinking on the cost-benefit again.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of protection in Windows.  But it's all there to protect the your users from you, not the other way around.

Comment: Not only. Memory protection protects you from people messing up pointers - but also from some memory injection attacks. But yes, generally the protection is more from the programmer, not for it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact of decompliation is: "As long as a computer can still execute it, it can also still decompile it."

Execution is a process that translates binary into actions.

Decompliation is a process that translates binary into code.

If one is blocked, the other is blocked as well.

Obfuscation can make it *harder to read the decompiled code*. But that is about all it can do.

> I store some pretty sensitive strings within the application, and though I try my best to keep them encrypted or in the local sqlite database, there is always that one, single point of failure that leaves the entire application vulnerable

Every string, is only as save as the place you keep it at. The same applies for encryption keys. There are 2 limited workarounds:

- if it is around comparing the input to something in the backend - like you do with passwords - [password security](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) can work. Modern PW security means not even the **Adminsitrator** can figure out the passwored, yet you can still compare user input to it.
- You could move the strings into a seperate application. Instead of giving applications the SQL Server Connection string, you give it access to a WebService that you control. Only the WebService actually knows how to contact the Database.

It depends on your practical scenario what you can do. But in the end, if a string or other peice of information is to be useable, it is vulnerable in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already acknowledged these facts in my question."I am aware that an executable has to run in memory, and this in itself makes it vulnerable. And a determined attacker can eventually decompile an application. However, I want to make this process as expensive as possible."

Comment: @Najeeb I updated my answer with some possible solutions